# rewrite allfile.php file to allfile.html using htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i want rewrite the all file of php extension to html

example like this

```
www.mydomain.com/file.php to www.mydomain.com/file.html
```

I am put this code on my htaccess

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm
```

But it will not work

what can i do for work this code

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [R=permanent]
```

Comment: i was put this code on my htaccess but it's not working, The url was not changed artem

Comment: Have you changed it in your browser? You need to have `www.mydomain.com/file.html` in address bar. Or you want all users that are going to `www.mydomain.com/file.php` will view `www.mydomain.com/file.html`?

Comment: What do you have in address bar of your browser?

Comment: www.mydoamin.com/index.php only working. if i put www.mydoamin.com/index.html this one not working frnd. i activated mod_rewrite on my apache config file. still not working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21719/discussion-between-artem-l-and-user1799277)